# How can the Java compiler know were are the packages I create?

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is any way that allow us to import packages in a class using a relative path.

To set an analogy, in html you can use a relative path to set an hyperlink.

For example, given this Files Structure:

```
    Folder: "A"
          |
          |____________ Folder: "B"
          |            |
          |            |
          |            |
          |            |_________  File html: "Link.html"
          | 
          |   
          |
          |________ File html: "Index.html"
```

So, in the file "Link.html" I can set this Hyperlink:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
           <title>Link</title>
      </head>
      <body>
           <main>
             <h1>You are in the file "Link"</h1>

               <!--This would be the hyperlink-->
               <a href="../Index.html"> Go to Index </a>

          </main>
      </body>
</html>
```

My question is:
Could I create a package for example in folder "B" and import the class from that folder "B" in a java file which would be in folder "A"?
I mean without using "classpath" (I don't say without using "sourcepath" too, because I'm not sure about how it works).

```
    Folder: "A"
          |
          |____________ Folder: "B"
          |            |
          |            |
          |            |
          |            |_________  File Java: "Example.java"
          | 
          |   
          |
          |________ File Java: "Main.Java"
```

Moreover, could I set an absolute path in a java file directly to import a package without having to tell the compiler, manually, where the packages are through classpath? (Like in html?)

I mean something like this example but when importing a package in java:

```
 <a href="C:\Users\Pc2\Desktop\A\Index.html"> Go to Index </a>
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Anyway, `import` doesn't care where the package/class you import is in the filesystem, just that it's in the classpath, so no, you can't give an absolute path with `import`, but you can when you pass the classpath through the command line when compiling/running.

Comment: "Can I make Java recognize a particular folder without using classpath" is akin to asking "can I make a smoothie without a blender". You have a problem and know the tool that's used to solve the problem. Why do you not want to use the tool that's very clearly designed for this specific purpose?

Comment: @Camy07 so is Example.java in package `A.B` and Main.java in package `A`? Then `Main` just has to `import A.B.Example`. I'm not sure I understand whether that's what you mean.

Comment: @Fererico-klez-Culloca In fact, you are right, only I was confused because I didn't know that in order to compile it properly I had to do it in the parent of the "Folder a", instead of inside of it, because it gave me the error of "The declared package does not match the expected package"

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there is any way that allow us to import packages in a class using a relative path.

No.  Java doesn't support that.  Package names are fully qualified when you define them and fully qualified when you use them.

---

> My question is: Could I create a package for example in folder "B" and import the class from that folder "B" in a java file which would be in folder "A"?

For the OpenJDK Java tool chain, and anything else that uses the same class resolution mechanisms<sup>1</sup>, the folder name structure must map to the package structure.  So assuming that the folder above `A` is the root of your (source or binary) class folder tree, then your `Main.java` file needs a `package` declaration

```
package A;
```

and your `Example.java` file needs a `package` declaration:

```
package A.B;
```

(Note that case is significant, and package names `A` and `B` are a Java style violation.)

Class `Example` can import `Main` and vice versa, but they **must** use the fully qualified package names to do that; i.e.

```
import A.Main;
import A.B.Example;
```

Q: Can you trick the compiler / runtime by having a class / package naming scheme that doesn't correspond to the file / folder structure?

A: No.  Either the Java compiler or runtime will fail to find classes or it will detect that there is a mismatch a class's fully qualified and the place where it was found.  In both cases you will get an error.

Q:  Can you import by file pathname?

A:  No.  The Java language doesn't permit this. Just ... no.

---

> I mean without using "classpath" (I don't say without using "sourcepath" too, because I'm not sure about how it works).

That doesn't make sense.  You cannot "not use" a classpath.  If there is no classpath, the Java tools cannot find your code.  There is always a classpath ... even if it is just the current directory; i.e. ".".

---

<sup>1 - As far as I am aware, this covers all current practical Java implementations.  However, it is technically possible (and permitted by the Java **Language** Specification) for a Java implementation to use some other mechanism for organizing and locating source code or binary code "entities".</sup>

Comment: I think I'm starting to get the point. I will have to go more in depth with those concepts of "Classpath" and "Sourcepath".

Comment: Although I'm still a bit confused about how the root is set. I mean, I know that the root of a directory tree is the first directory of the tree.  But, I'm not sure about how or why we can set a relative root in our projects. As far as I know the root of every computer is often the letter of our hard disk, am I wrong?

Comment: I suggest you read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: Java packages are used to do just that, but the CLASSPATH is still in use. The default class loader will look under the CLASSPATH for classes and expect them to be located based on their package names. (There are other class loaders that have different behaviors, but mostly you will use the default one.)

For your second question: No you cannot. As explained above, the default class loader will look under the CLASSPATH for any class you import, and will try to locate based on the package name of classes. (Again, assuming you use the default class loader.)

Java packages are the standard way of structuring your code, and for most cases this structure is also replicated on the file system (for both source and class files).

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering myself because I don't want to confused anyone else.

As far as I've understood:
The "Relative path" I was looking for were in fact java packages.

As @Fererico-klez-Culloca said, having this example:

```
 Folder: "A"
          |
          |____________ Folder: "B"
          |            |
          |            |
          |            |
          |            |_________  File Java: "Example.java"
          | 
          |   
          |
          |________ File Java: "Main.Java"
```

Main just has to import A.B.Example.

However, there are 2 things that must be considered:

1. Main has to have "package A", Example.java has to have "package A.B".
2. Supposing I'm using visual studio, in order to compile it I can't do it opening the folder "a" directly as it will give me an error. As I still have to understand more in depth how this works, I'll quote another person words:

"In Visual Studio, you need the "source folder" to be the folder above a, not a itself, because package names are resolved relative to the source folder. "

A way to resolve this would be creating another folder, so the files schema could be something like this:

```
Folder: "Project_Folder"
        |
        |
    Folder: "A"
            |
            |____________ Folder: "B"
            |            |
            |            |
            |            |
            |            |_________  File Java: "Example.java"
            | 
            |   
            |
            |________ File Java: "Main.Java"
```

Having that, I have to open the folder (project) in "Project_Folder", so that the compiler can find the folder "a", and identify it as a package.

Although "absolute path" doesn't really exist in java, It's true that "classpath" can act similar to it, nevertheless classpath and "absolute path" (of html) are not exactly the same.